# React-native: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_this.props.navigation.navigate') onpress

Tags: javascript, react-native, navigation

```
const AppStackLog = createDrawerNavigator(
  {

    Login: {
      screen: LogintStack,
      navigationOptions: (navOpt) => ({
        drawerLabel: ({focused}) =>(
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button]} onPress={() => this.navigation.navigate('App')}>
         <Text><Icon

            size={17}
            name="log-in"
            family="Galio"
            color={focused ? 'white' : materialTheme.COLORS.MUTED} />
       <Text size={18}>        Logout</Text></Text>       
      </TouchableOpacity>
        ),
      }),
    },



  },
  Menu
);

export default createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    App: AppStack,
    Home: HomeStack,
    Auth:AppStackLog,
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'App',
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` is not going to point to some particular component, it's going to point to whatever `this` was equal to when this code was defined. Instead, the navOpt parameter has what you need on it:

```
<TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button]} onPress={() => navOpt.navigation.navigate('App')}>
```

Comment: Are you saying it didn't work? Please tell me what failed.